# Как изменить исходные данные из БД PostreSQL для создания портфолио?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть ряд кейсов на основе конфиденциальной информации (источник данных - БД на PostgrSQL).
Мне нужно сделать портфолио на основе выполненной работы.
Я думаю, что проще будет сделать копию базы данных с измененными данными и использовать ее в портфолио.
Как я могу сделать измененную резервную копию, без значительного искажения данных (чтобы не было необходимости кардинально переделывать уже выполненную работу).

Comment: Да простейшим UPDATE заменить конфиденциальные данные на нумерованный фэйк. Скажем, фамилии на "Фамилия 1", "Фамилия 2" и т.п. Надеюсь, с нормальностью схемы всё в порядке?

Comment: Тут немного в другом проблема. С числовыми данными. На основе анализа сделано много различных выводов и рекомендаций, и были использованы математические модели для прогнозов. Как лучше изменить числовые данные, сохранив их структуру, чтобы ранее сделанные выводы в целом остались актуальными?

Comment: Вообще несвязанные задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копия базы данных делается следующем образом.

В начале делается backup текущей базы:

```
pg_dump -U username -d original_database > original_backup.sql
```

Потом создается новая пустая база:

```
createdb -U username portfolio_database
```

Далее backup переносится в новую базу:

```
psql -U username -d portfolio_database < original_backup.sql
```

Готово. База копирована.
Копия сделана включая структуру и всю содержащуюся информацию.

Дальше можно вносить изменения в новую базу данных.

Comment: К сожалению у меня команда pg_dump не работает. Я подключаюсь к базе через SQL Shell (psql). Команда: pg_dump -U username -d original_database > 'E:\dumb\original_backup.sql'.